# DL380 G9 - ESXi v6 u3 showing SCSI disk as normal,degraded

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, vmware-vsphere

We have installed Vmware ESXi v6 u3 on a DL380 G9. We did the raid in the Intelligent provisioning during system startup, after which we did the Install. But all the volumes created are showing up as `normal,degraded`.

Is there any reason for this.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the error or a screenshot? What does the system health LED on the physical server show? Any red/amber lights?

Comment: @ewwhite: Please see the updated post

Comment: Can you answer my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the front of the server and take a visual check of the array status.

What does the system health LED array on the physical server show?

[image]

You can also check the disk status from the ILO interface.

If you have access to the ESXi host's command line, you can run:

```
/opt/smartstorageadmin/ssacli/bin/ssacli ctrl all show config
```

or

```
/opt/smartstorageadmin/ssacli/bin/ssacli ctrl all show config detail
```

Those should show you the full array status.

Comment: DL380 G9 doesn't have the LED array, but I asked someone to physically check the drives (as the server is remotely located), there is no amber light. I tried to use the command ssacli, it says ssacli not found. But it shows me listed under /opt/smartstorageadmin/ssacli/bin. Do you know why it shows me not found

Comment: I figured it out I need to use it with the esxcli to get it working. THanks.

Comment: What did you figure out?

Comment: For the command, how to use the command.

Comment: With this command you mentioned it shows all my drives healthy, plus no amber light on the front of the server which tell me there is nothing wrong with the drives. Could this be due to the path. As this is a built in controller it only shows me a single path to the logical drive. Could it be because of this.

Comment: I used it like this: `esxcli ssacli cmd -q 'ctrl all show config'`. It works this way for me. If I go to the path `/path/smartstorageadmin/ssacli/bin/ssacli ctrl all show config` it says ssacli not found. Does it work for this way.

Answer (score 0):

VMware esx expect at least two paths from hypervisor to datastore. If only one path is available, status is as you see it.